# angular ng-checked interferes with foundation

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a bug due to an interference between angular and foundation.

Basically, I just copy pasted [the example provided in the doc](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive%3angChecked):

```
Check me to check both: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="master"><br/>
<input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="master">
```

Two cases:

- when I have `$(document).foundation();`: nice design, example does not work
- when I comment `$(document).foundation();`: no more foundation goodness, example works

I guess it's due to the additional markup added by foundation but still, it does not help  much.

I am looking for a way to get both... any of you ran across this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call a library initializer like `.foundation()` on an Angular-driven DOM because the DOM elements actually don't exist until Angular creates them.

This is a major speed-bump with any client-side MVC framework, but be assured you are not alone in wanting to achieve this type of functionality.

The proper way to use Foundation with Angular would be to wrap its widgets in [Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

Here are some resources to help you:

- [How do I “think in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)
- [An approach to use jQuery Plugins with AngularJS](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/)
- [Using the D3.js Visualization Library with AngularJS](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3.html)
- [AngularStrap - Bootstrap directives for AngularJS](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/)
- [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/)
- [Angular Modules](http://ngmodules.org/)

Comment: I just need to keep checkboxes design one way or another. Iguess I should tell foundation to leave them alone

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom directive instead of using the ng-checked, which will handle the foundation's additional markups. It may not be idle way, but it ll solve your issue, as it knows too much about the foundation implementation etc.

Directive snippet from [original blog post](http://www.ramandv.com/blog/zurb-foundation-custom-form-angular-js-ng-checked-2/)

```
directive('ngCheckedFoundation',['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    function markCheckBox(value, scope, element, attr) {
        //timeout to avoid the foundation javascript action changed by this directive
        $timeout(function() {
                if(value) {
                    attr.$set("checked", true);
                    element.next().addClass('checked');
                }
                else {
                    attr.$set("checked", false);
                    element.next().removeClass('checked');
                }
        }, 200);
    }

    function link (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attr["ngCheckedFoundation"], function(n,o) {
          if(n != o) {
            markCheckBox(n, scope, element, attr);
          }
        });
        markCheckBox(scope.$eval(attr.ngCheckedFoundation), scope, element, attr);
    }

    return({
        link: link,
        restrict: "A",
    });
}])
```