# Bind AngularJS data model to a Foundation checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to bind a model (a `bool` value) to a checkbox made with Foundation (Zurb). 
I made a small demo showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JmZes/53/

One way could be just doing a function that will trigger on-click, but I'd like to make sure that there isn't any other (better) possible way, like binding the value directly to Angular and let it manage the state of the UI.

Any idea if what I'm trying to do is possible?

Regards

EDIT: Wrong demo link

Answer (score 0):

I made it :)

I used `$timeout` inside a function from `ng-click`. A little bit ugly, but that's the best I think it can be done.

http://jsfiddle.net/JmZes/54/

Comment: Related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622349/angular-ng-checked-interferes-with-foundation/19829526#19829526